# Assign output of h5disp to variable

Tags: matlab, hdf

I am using MATLAB R2012a to read an hdf5 data file using the the function `h5disp`. How can I assign the output to a variable or write it to disk?  Is there a way to redirect the output in MATLAB? My goal is to read in many files and output a summary of their contents to disk in a format equal to or similar to `h5disp`.

Like

```
h = output(h5disp(myhdf5file))
```

or to disk like

```
h5disp(myhdf5file) > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Do you want `h= h5info(myhdf5file)` ?

Comment: @sardausama Yet that's exactly what I want, unfortunately, the h5disp only outputs to the command window and no value of the output is returned. So I'm trying to redirect that output to h instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`h5info`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5info.html) to store that information in the workspace i.e.

```
h = h5info(myhdf5file);
```

or you can use [`diary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) to write the output of [`h5disp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5disp.html) to a text file.

```
diary outputfile.txt
h5disp(myhdf5file)
diary off
```